# NAS OS that will sync to MS Sharepoint?

Tags: freenas, nas

Right now I'm using FreeNAS for my NAS, but I want it to sync with Microsoft Sharepoint so that there are multiple points of access for my users. Is there an operating system I can put on my NAS that will sync nicely this way?

Comment: It might be helpful if you'd state the make and the model of your NAS hardware.

Comment: The model of the hardware is irrelevant, since user64914 said he uses `FreeNAS`. Any NAS that uses x86/amd64 will apply to this question.